# Why is GeoCoordinateWatcher's DesiredAccuracy property readonly?

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8

This code;

```
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
    watcher.DesiredAccuracy = GeoPositionAccuracy.High;
```

...fails with: "*Property or indexer 'System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.DesiredAccuracy' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only*"

Why would `DesiredAccuracy` be readonly? If that's really so, it should be named `Accuracy`, or perhaps `AttemptedAccuracy`, but not `DesiredAccuracy`.

Comment: You can choose it by passing it to the constructor. So I don't see where the problem with calling it `DesiredAccuracy` is.

Comment: Read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.desiredaccuracy.aspx)...

Comment: The docs are Spartan and unclear.

Comment: CodesInChaos's answer appears to answer your question, although you may want to avoid sentences like your last in your questions going forward, they dilute your question while simply adding discussion points (which are better let to comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GeoPositionAccuracy` property is set via a [constructor argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792401.aspx). Its name includes `Desired` because it was the accuracy that was desired when the watcher was constructed.

They have several stern warnings about using an accuracy of `High`, which leads me to believe the property is read-only is because of the effort involved in switching the desired accuracy frequently may incur additional charges to the user.